# Why don't jQuery Mobile prefetched "single-page" pages work exactly like "multi-page" pages

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a website that consists of a bunch of single-page-template jQuery Mobile pages that are linked to each other using prefetching and caching.  All pages exist in the DOM (after they are prefetched).

This works fine on my desktop browser.  However, when I browse my site using my HTC EVO 3D Android phone (either the default browser or the Opera browser), switching between pages acts like I'm actually going to an external page.  In other words, the browser's address bar appears momentarily, then the page turns white, then the new page loads, then the address bar goes away.

I would expect the behavior to be exactly that of a multi-page-template.  For example, if you browse the multi-page-template in the jQuery Mobile documentation, you can switch from one page to another very smoothly.  The browser address toolbar does not pop up, and there is no white flickering in between pages.  However, if you browse the "persistent toolbar" example (which uses prefetching to load all the pages in the example), you will see the same behavior that my site is experiencing.  The browser's address bar will appear, the page will turn white, the next page will render, then the address bar will go away.

So how do I make my prefetched pages act like the multi-page template without having to rewrite my site to use the multi-page-template?

For reference, here are the jQuery Mobile persistent toolbar demo and multi-page demo that I believe should work exactly the same (in regard to URL address bar appearing):

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/toolbars/footer-persist-a.html

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/pages/multipage-template.html

Answer (score 0):

Unless your initial page links directly to all of your other pages with the `data-prefetch` attribute on your `<a>` link tags, those pages will not be prefetched and cached. I state this because your question implies that there is some chaining with your pages which is not supported. You can load also load and cache them via the API.

`$.mobile.loadPage( pageUrl, { showLoadMsg: false } );`

Are you able to actually inspect the DOM on your mobile Android device?

Is there any chance the pages are being flushed from the DOM based on a memory constraint? I am not aware of any specifics in the jQM docs on this scenario but at some point you will fill the cache.

Comment: All of links do have the data-prefetch attribute.  And also the persistant footer demo links all have that attribute (URL below).  I have looked at the DOM, and all pages are prefetched into the DOM.  There is no server hit when switching pages... just the address bar opening up temporarily.  After more research, I *think* it has something to do with the way jQuery Mobile uses hashes in the URL.
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/toolbars/footer-persist-a.html

Comment: You cannot modify the hashes used by your URLs within jQM. jQM uses hashes for navigation and to maintain browser history.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not looking to mess with jQM's navigation or history.  My question still remains.

Comment: Even better, I can point you to the jQuery Mobile demos that I reference in my question.  The prefetched, single-page demo is:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/toolbars/footer-persist-a.html

and the multi-page template demo is:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/pages/multipage-template.html

Comment: I've updated the end of my question to make it easier to get to these examples.

Comment: What happens if you use jQM 1.2?

Comment: I think what is confusing about your question is that you are comparing single and multi page templates when really you are dealing with an issue that appears to be specific to your HTC device when using prefetching and a single page template. You might consider reworking your question. If you can isolate a bug, post that on the jQM git site.

Comment: Hmm... so the reason for my comparison is to show that my device is capable of "switching pages" without showing the address bar - if you follow the multi-page-template. But that it incorrectly shows the address bar if you follow the single-page-with-prefetch-template.  This does seem like a bug, so I've posted the question on the jQM git site.  Unfortunately, they're ignoring it for now and said they'd take a look at it in version 1.4.